# Avoid test_depend in rosdep install

Tags: ros-melodic, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

## Problem

I'm seeing `rosdep install` returns error when it can't find a package (say PKG_A) defined in `test_depend` in `package.xml` as a dependency, where PKG_A can't exist in the env I'm running.

## Question

Is there a way to continue having PKG_A as a `test_depend`, but let `rosdep install` pass w/o returning error?

## Background

- In my work, build and test happen on different environment. Some pkgs are only for test and they cannot be present in the build environment.
- My understanding is that the dependency defined in `test_depend` is not an exception when `rosdep install` tries to resolve dependency defined in `package.xml`. [#q115526](https://answers.ros.org/question/115526/is-test_depend-actually-used-for-anything/?answer=116071#post-id-116071), where the author of test_depend concept and REP-0140 discusses its purpose, reads as below and this supports my understanding:

  > Unfortunately, it currently does not resolve build or configuration dependencies needed by those tests. Use a <build_depend> for that instead.
  > :
  > Once [REP-0140](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/59) is approved and implemented <test_depend> will work for build and configuration dependencies, as well as for execution dependencies. That is a definite improvement, but the packaging restrictions will remain.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370946/avoid-test_depend-in-rosdep-install/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2021-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This would have a positive answer if [ros-infrastructure/rosdep#789](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/pull/789) ever gets merged.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0